# How to verify object with changing index in protractor?

Tags: protractor

Want to verify notifications on particular menu (Auction), unable to use indexing as it changes with presence/absence of notifications on different menus.
In my application I have multiple menus and all get notifications if other users have requested.
Now the problem I am facing is, One of the menu on which I am working currently (Auctions) takes lots of time to show notification (taking time to load that number) and I want to validate if notification exists on Auction menu, which is failing even after using browser.sleep

I am not able to use

```
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element.all(by.css('.notification.ng-binding')).get(0)), 10000);
```

as get(0) can consider notification on News menu if notification count does not appear on any other menu before it. Check the screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

Now, I need your help in identifying notification only on Auction menu. I don't know how to select that specific element.
Please suggest.

Comment: protractor automatically wait for the page to load, so basically you don't need to give browser.sleep(). But still browser.sleep should work.   If you are not able find any answers try using a tool called ELEMENTOR. It helps you to find the suitable locator for the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the parent selector and search for descendant element that contains class as `notification`  from the DOM.try the below selector.

```
element(by.css("[element-type='auction'] .notification"))
```